# print the bibliography divided by sections

Tags: biblatex

How is it possible to print the bibliography divided into sections? I tried to use this construct but it prints all the bibliography first and then all the sections.

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Bibliografia}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=book, title={Libri}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=article, title={Articoli}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=misc, title={Sitografia}]
```

**Additional problem**

The answer by Moewe is wonderful, but there are remaining problems.

In the table of contents the item `"Riferimenti bibliografici"` continues to be present. What can I do to stop it from showing?

[image: Bibliografia e Riferimenti bibliografici]

Also I have noticed that, although there is the `\listofcodes` code index, it does it not appear in the index. Why?

[image: list of code does not appear in index]

**All code used**

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[italian]{babel}             
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{paralist}{\obeyspaces\global\let =\space}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid, useprefix, hyperref, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\ringraziamenti

\sommario

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofcodes

\mainmatter
\include{chap_one}
\include{chap_two}
\include{chap_three}
\include{chap_four}
\include{chap_five}
\include{chap_six}

\appendix
\include{app_a}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\refname}
\nocite{*}

\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc, title={Bibliografia}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=book, title={Libri}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=article, title={Articoli}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=misc, title={Sitografia}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=misc, title={Misc}]  
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, nottype=book, nottype=article, nottype=online, title={Did I miss anything?}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the two lines `\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\refname}` before the bibliography. They add another, superfluous bibliography heading to the ToC.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. If you just want to print the overall heading without a bibliography, you need `\printbibheading` instead of `\printbibliography`.

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,aksin,cicero,itzhaki,itzhaki,baez/online,geer}

\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc, title={Bibliografia}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=book, title={Libri}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=article, title={Articoli}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=online, title={Sitografia}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,
  nottype=book, nottype=article, nottype=online,
  title={Did I miss anything?}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Split bibliography with overall heading.]

Note that I added a last `\printbibliography` with complementary `nottype`s to check that we didn't miss any entries (in this example the `@thesis` entry `geer`). You may not want this in the final version of your document, but it can be a handy tool during the writing process.

Comment: I did as you advised me and it works wonderfully. The only thing is that I notice in the list of contents the item `"Riferimenti bibliografici"` continues to be present. How can I do to stop it from showing?
[1]

Also I have noticed only now that although there is the `\listofcodes` code index, why does it not appear in the index?
[2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxv5w.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng6xz.png

Comment: @MMas In the MWE I posted there is no unnecessary "Riferimenti bibliografici" even if I add a `\tableofcontents`. If you get that in your bibliography, some other code that you haven't shown us (and that is not used in my code) must be causing this entry. We will only be able to help you properly if you can show us a short example document (in the style of the code in my answer) that reproduces the effect. Without such an MWE we won't be able to investigate the issue any further. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6255/35864

Comment: @MMas I should add that the problem with `\listofcodes` is a very different issue and encourage you to ask a new question about that (ideally also with an MWE, otherwise people would have to guess what you are doing and there are too many unknowns).

Comment: I posted above all the code used @moewe